# rails 4.2.0 ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I have upgraded rails 4.2.0 and spree 3.0

Once I run rspec then I am getting following error, It is showing me rspec ActionController::UrlGenerationError in rails 4.2.0, I have lots of googled but did not find any solution, Please find below log:

```
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb"=>[10]}}
F

Failures:

  1) MessagesController create with valid message sends message and shows flash notice
     Failure/Error: get "contact-us"
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"contact-us", :controller=>"messages"}
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `generate'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:758:in `generate'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:753:in `generate_extras'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:748:in `extra_keys'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:208:in `assign_parameters'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:619:in `process'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:65:in `process'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `block in process'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `catch'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:72:in `_catch_warden'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:19:in `process'
     # /home/rails22/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:508:in `get'
     # ./spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02445 seconds (files took 9.1 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:10 # MessagesController create with valid message sends message and shows flash notice
```

Mine Routes file:

```
match 'messages/contact-us' => 'messages#contact_us', via: [:get]
```

rake routes log:

```
rake routes | grep "contact-us"
                                         contact_us GET    /contact-us(.:format)                                          redirect(301, /support#/contact-us)
                                            contact GET    /contact(.:format)                                             redirect(301, /support#/contact-us)
                                messages_contact_us GET    /messages/contact-us(.:format)                                 messages#contact_us
```

Comment: the error is about contact*-*us and there is contact*_*us in the route.

Comment: I have tried, but gives me same error

Comment: Try changing match to get

Comment: yes, I had changed to get, but get errors same

Comment: a stupid question: you have this action in the controller? :)

Comment: @Michal It's not a controller or action error, it's a routing error. Please show us your `rake routes` command.

Comment: I have "contact_us" action in controller but route is "contact-us"

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm, I have added rake routes log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug was introduced in Spree 3.0, by [this commit](https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/bd881d9d34e418eeb73a30440013bfeb31ebea45) which cleans up the way Spree Controller tests specify which routes to use. You are likely seeing this error because you are testing a route that is outside of `Spree::Core::Engine.routes`, but your `spec_helper.rb` still includes this line:

```
config.include Spree::TestingSupport::ControllerRequests, type: :controller
```

## How to fix

### Option 1)

Fix just the spec in question by reassigning the routes used for the test. Example:

```
describe MessagesController, type: :controller do
  routes { Rails.application.routes }  # <--- add this line

  describe '#index' do
    before do
      get :index
    end

    specify do
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

### Option 2)

If you do NOT have any tests in your project that hit Spree controllers, or anything in the Spree route namespace, you can simply **remove** this line from your project's `spec/spec_helper.rb` or `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
config.include Spree::TestingSupport::ControllerRequests, type: :controller
```

## How this happened

- Previously, the Spree engine routes were specified with the `use_route` parameter inside of `process_spree_action` and `process_spree_xhr_action`. They did not interfere with controller tests under your own namespace.
- Rails 4.2 deprecated `use_route`.
- Spree changed to the newer `routes { Spree::Core::Engine.routes }`, which is now applied to everything that includes `Spree::TestingSupport::ControllerRequests`.
- This is all because Rspec has [admittedly poor Engine support](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/labels/Engine), so the community has been doing their best to make the tools work together.